# Problem with Session unpack

Tags: asp.net

I have some problems with this code:

```
    private void BoxVisibility(bool email, bool link, Control linkButton)
    {
        mainEmail.Visible = email;
        foreach (Control c in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
        {
            c.Visible = false;
        }
        if (linkButton != null)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
            linkButton.Visible = link;
        }

    }
```

when I send to method Control all is ok, but when at first I put Control in `Session['temp'] = Control`, and then invoke the method like `BoxVisibility(false, true, (Control) this.Session['temp'])` in this case `Control linkButton.Visible = link;` doesn't take `true`, He's still remain `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The "control" is a *reference* to a particular instance for this particular page.

The Page is recreated on every request, so a reference to an old instance of your control is no longer valid. So don't store controls in anything (Session, ViewState, static fields) that lives longer than the single request. Local (instance) fields of your page are safe.

Comment: I think this problem in another. You see when I try to debug my app I try change object property _before_ page reload.

Comment: also, I try get new object references and change them, and i get the same results..